# MethodNotAllowedHttpException - Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have two buttons in the home page - *Reader* & *Writer* - which directs the user to the registration form with knowing the `profession`.

```
Route::post('register', [
'as' => 'profession_path',
'uses' => 'ProfessionController@displayForm'
]);

Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
```

When I normally go to `.com/auth/register` I can register the user successfully, so the form works perfectly.

ProfessionController

```
class ProfessionController extends Controller
{

   public function displayForm()
    {
    $input = \Input::get();
    $profession = $input['profession'];
    return view('auth/register', ['profession' => $profession]);
    }
}
```

It also works successfully when I click on the button and redirect to `.com/register` and recognises `$profession`. However, when I click on the submit button on registration form (which is normally located in `.com/auth/register` and works successful in there), it throws an error:

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 201:

Where am I missing?

Comment: Are you trying to use the same register form for both reader and writer?
What is the difference in the registration between a reader and a writer?

Comment: Yes, I put a hidden field in the registration form as `$profession` so the guest doesn't have to select it again. But if the guest comes directly to the registration form page, it shows radio buttons. The difference between reader and writer will differ after the sign in.

Comment: How do you call that field in the controller?

Comment: I didn't yet. Is that the reason? Should I put `'profession' => 'required',` in  `protected function validator(array $data)` and `'profession' => $data['profession'],` in `protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([` ?

Comment: Well I think you should start by defining how are you going to save the user in the database, so maybe it could help.

Comment: Please add the `<form>` declaration from your register view to the question. The `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` is telling you that you that a route doesn't exist for the HTTP request you are making. Maybe you are making PUT/PATH/POST request but only have a `get()` route setup, or vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per your question i think you are doing wrong in your form .
in your route you are doing  get and post request.

```
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
```

usually form submit is post method,that you have to specify in your form like

```
{{ Form::open(array('method' => 'post')) }}

{{ Form::open(array('method' => 'get')) }}
```

if you are using normal html then

```
<form method="POST" action="http://currenturl" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<form method="GET" action="http://currenturl" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

laravel route request look like following

```
Route::get() will respond to GET requests.
Route::post() will respond to POST requests.
Route::delete() will respond to DELETE requests (this includes when adding the custom DELETE
Route::put() will respond to PUT requests (this includes when adding the custom PUT
Route::patch() will respond to PATCH requests (this includes when adding the custom PATCH
```